# Extract date and time from string in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I am parsing some log files and would like to extract only date and time data. The log files look like this:

```
2017-03-01 12:00:15.896 Sync DeliveryContacts: 00:00.011(00.011) end
2017-03-01 12:00:16.473 SyncTables(): 00:00.293(00.293) end
2017-03-01 12:02:48.636 00:00.000(00.000) end
```

EDIT - this is also a possible line in file:

```
2017-03-01 12:00:15.896 Sync Delivery Contacts: 00:00.011(00.011) Started with predefined delay (10:00.000) end
```

I would like to get 3 columns like this:

```
[YYYY-MM-DD] [hh:mm:ss.000] [mm:ss.000]
```

or:

```
2017-03-01 12:00:15.896 00:00.011
2017-03-01 12:00:16.473 00:00.293
2017-03-01 12:02:48.636 00:00.000
```

strings will always start with DateTime (first 2 columns), and the second time data will always be 9 characters long.

I have tried:

```
fgrep "end" *.txt -a /
 | awk '{ print $1 " " $2 " " $4 }'
```

but that works only for the second line in my example.

I am thinking that I could get the first 2 columns with awk but have no clue how to get that 3 time column.

Comment: You don't need to use both `fgrep` and `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With single ***gawk*** approach:

```
awk '{r=""; for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){ r=r$i }; 
      match(r, /\<([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3})\(/, a); print $1,$2,a[1];}' file
```

The output:

```
2017-03-01 12:00:15.896 00:00.011
2017-03-01 12:00:16.473 00:00.293
2017-03-01 12:02:48.636 00:00.000
```

---

`for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){ r=r$i };` - concatenating field values starting from the 3rd field

`match(r, /([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3})\(/, a)` - matches time data `[mm:ss.000]` within "collected" field data

Comment: Best answer because of its flexibility. It was easier to change to my needs

Comment: That's far more complicated than necessary and you should mention it's gawk-specific due to the 3rg arg for match(). You should escape the `.` in the RE btw.

Comment: @EdMorton, *That's far more* unified if "time-data" is not at `$(NF-2)` but somewhere between, Btw, not *3rg* (as you wrote), but 3rd. I forgot to escape the dot

Comment: But time-data IS at $(NF-2) in every line of the example input the OP provided. There are many other possibilities we'd have to consider if the OPs data isn't as he showed. Maybe the time isn't always 2 digits and you've have to change `[0-9]{2}` to `[0-9]{1,2}` or similar? Maybe there aren't always parens after it? Maybe it can be present multiple times on the line? My point is simply that for the question the OP posted you don't need such a complicated solution, and if the OPs data is NOT as posted then any solution is just a guess so why not just help the OP solve the stated problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk:

```
fgrep "end" *.txt -a | awk '{sub(/\(.*/, "", $(NF-1)); print $1, $2, $(NF-1)}'

2017-03-01 12:00:15.896 00:00.011
2017-03-01 12:00:16.473 00:00.293
2017-03-01 12:02:48.636 00:00.000
```

`sub` function is used to strip all the text starting with `(`

Answer (score 1):

Given the example in your question, all you need is:

```
$ awk -F'[ (]' '{print $1, $2, $(NF-2)}' file
2017-03-01 12:00:15.896 00:00.011
2017-03-01 12:00:16.473 00:00.293
2017-03-01 12:02:48.636 00:00.000
```

If that's NOT all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input and expected output.

Comment: I edited the examples. Basically, I couldn't rely on that there will not be more spaces or parenthesis in the same line. I understand know why that was important information for answering the question

Comment: I see you added a new input line but you didn't add the expected output for that line so it's use is pretty limited. Also that line cannot be present in the input to the awk script since it wouldn't have been produced by the `fgrep "end"` so having it present is more confusing than useful.

Comment: Luckily an answer has been found. Thank you for your input, made me look into awk with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $1,$2, substr($(NF-1),1,9)}' file

2017-03-01 12:00:15.896 00:00.011
2017-03-01 12:00:16.473 00:00.293
2017-03-01 12:02:48.636 00:00.000
```